# ruby: fix mostly-utf8 strings

Tags: ruby, utf-8

I have input data (via File.popen) that is mostly utf8, but occasionally there are iso8859-1 characters in them. I want everything that is not a valid utf8 sequence interpreted as iso8859-1 and replaced with the corresponding (two-byte) utf-8 sequence (and the result as an UTF-8 encoded string).

What is an efficient way to do this in ruby? This will treat an entire `git log` output, so it should be reasonably fast.

Comment: Do you know when ISO8859-1 characters are incoming? Otherwise if you don't, then it's going to be impossible to recode reliably.

Comment: No. I just want to consider ISO what isn't valid UTF8 - it's pretty improbable that there will be two consecutive ISO characters that also form a valid UTF8 sequence (except for texts of on-topic joke t-shirts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since ruby 2.1.0 (afaik) you can use `scrub` to do this kind of ugly encoding stuff:

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-scrub

> If the string is invalid byte sequence then replace invalid bytes with
>   given replacement character, else returns self. If block is given,
>   replace invalid bytes with returned value of the block.

```
"abc\u3042\x81".scrub #=> "abc\u3042\uFFFD"
"abc\u3042\x81".scrub("*") #=> "abc\u3042*"
"abc\u3042\xE3\x80".scrub{|bytes| '<'+bytes.unpack('H*')[0]+'>' } #=> "abc\u3042<e380>"
```

Comment: Exacly what I was hoping for. Except that I won't get off ruby 2.0 anytime soon, but that's not a fault of the answer.

Comment: you should be aware that ruby below 2.2 does not get any security fixes.

Comment: That is our sysadmin's problem and responsibility, and this code isn't network-facing. Distris do backport security patches.